# How to add ffmpeg to my android project and use them?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I am developing an Android project/app for video compression and that's how I came to know about ffmpeg. I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 OS and Eclipse IDE(ADT-bundle).

I came across many topics dealing with ffmpeg at StackOverflow but i can't clearly figure out where I can get the ffmpeg jar file and how to add it and use in my project.

Any advice from you will be of great help.

If ffmpeg is so tough to handle for a beginner in Android like me, then is there any other way to compress a video in android?

Comment: ffmpeg is a native library, so you would have to compile it with ndk

Answer (score 0):

If you're targetting Android 15 or greater version, try `MediaCodec` class.

May be [this](http://jffmpeg.sourceforge.net/) helps You.It's java porting of ffmpeg. Though it uses `JNI` internally,it provides java functions that hides the mess!!

Comment: I researched about 'MediaCodec', but it doesn't provides any way for video compression, right?

Comment: As far as i know, it supports encoding camera stream into AVC/H264. Everything you need about it can be [this](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/) I am looking for a way to encode random input video, such as raw images into videos!

Comment: you mean Bitmap to video? If so, then please notify me about your RND

Comment: @Rakesh Similar. Bitmap is RGB888 data, so likewise, i want to know how to use MediaCodec for this kind of data(RGB888,RGBA,RGB565,etc)